# Prove that $x^3+x+1$ splits in $Z_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

Let $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ and set $E=z_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$
prove that $f(x)$ splits in E that is find 3 distinct roots of $f(x)$ in $E$

---

**Questions**
found $[x^2+1]$ $[x^2+x+1]$ on my sloppy work. There are more than 3 roots if my notes are correct. If that is the case do we just use the irreducibles??

Another question I have is that what is [x]?? Is it a variable, some sort of constant. I know the book uses idertimenatn and has special properties.

Comment: $[x]$ is a coset.  You should get very solid on the definitions before proceeding.  $[x^2+1]$ and $[x^2+x+1]$ are not roots.  There are exactly three roots, and the third is the only one you haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer that uses a bit more theory.  First some generalities.  Suppose $F$ is a field, $f \in F[x]$ is irreducible and $K = \frac{F[x]}{(f(x))} = F(\theta)$ is the extension of $F$ obtained by adjoining a root $\theta$ of $f$ (which in your notation is $[x]$, the image of $x$ in the quotient).  Given $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(K/F)$, then it follows by the properties of ring homomorphisms and the fact that $\sigma$ is the identity on $F$ that $\sigma(\theta)$ is also a root of $f$, where
$$
\text{Aut}(K/F) = \{\sigma : K \to K \mid \sigma \text{ is a field automorphism}, \sigma|_F = \text{id}_F\} \, .
$$

Alright, now back to your question.  Let $\mathbb{F}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $\frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{(x^3 + x + 1)} = \mathbb{F}_2(\theta)$ is a field extension where $\theta$ is the image of $x$ in the quotient.  Now, over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (more generally we can replace $2$ by any prime $p$) we have one very special automorphism called the [Frobenius map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism):
\begin{align*}
\sigma: \mathbb{F}_2(\theta) &\to \mathbb{F}_2(\theta)\\
\alpha &\mapsto \alpha^2 \, .
\end{align*}
(This is a homomorphism by the [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream#Prime_characteristic).)  Then, by the first paragraph, $\sigma(\theta) = \theta^2$ and
$$
\sigma^2(\theta) = \theta^4 = \theta \theta^3 = \theta (\theta + 1) = \theta^2 + \theta
$$
are also roots of $f$.  (Note that $\sigma^3 = \text{id}_K$ and higher powers of $\sigma$ will just repeat the identity, $\sigma$, and $\sigma^2$.)  In fact one can show that any finite extension of finite fields has cyclic Galois group generated by the Frobenius map; cf. [this article](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/finitefields.pdf) by Keith Conrad.

Answer (score 1):

In the field $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$, one root of $X^3+X+1$ is $\alpha=x$, or more precisely the coset of $x$ with respect to the ideal $(x^3+x+1)$. You should be able to check quickly that the other two roots are $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^4$.

The reason for this is that $z\mapsto z^2$ is an automorphism of every finite field of characteristic two, and is identity on the prime field $\Bbb F_2$. So it carries any root $\rho$ of a polynomial $g(X)\in\Bbb F_2[X]$ to a root $\rho^2$ of $g$.