# Splitting field of a polynomial over Z_5

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Find the splitting field of the polynomial $$x^3+x+1$$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

I can see that the given polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ So, $$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_5 [x]}{(x^3+x+1)}$$ is a field and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the image of $x$ under the canonical map $$\pi \colon \mathbb{Z}_5[x]\to \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_5 [x]}{(x^3+x+1)}.$$
So, $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_5(\alpha)$ and it factorizes as $$x^3+x+1=(x-\alpha)(x^2+\alpha x+\alpha^2+1)$$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5(\alpha)$.

But now I can't conclude anything about $x^2+\alpha x+\alpha^2+1$.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the Frobenius map: if $\alpha$ is a root, then so are $\alpha^5$ and $(\alpha^5)^5$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn wow.! that's a quick way to see.! in general, this is true because in a char p field ( a_nx^n + . . . + a_0 )^p = a_n^px^pn + . . . + a_0^p ?

Comment: @Swarup Yes, and because the Frobenius map fixes the coefficients since they are in $\mathbb{F}_5$. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537229/prove-that-x3x1-splits-in-z-2x-x3x1/1537625#1537625) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: If $\alpha$ is a zero of $f(x)= x^3+x+1$, then by the Frobenius automorphism $a\mapsto a^5$, $\alpha^5$ and $\alpha^{25}$ are also zeros.
Hence, $f(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^5)(x-\alpha^{25})$.

Remark:

Since $\alpha$ is a zero, $\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0$ and so $\alpha^3=-\alpha - 1$.
Thus $\alpha^5 = -\alpha^3-\alpha^2 = -(-\alpha-1)-\alpha^2 = -\alpha^2+\alpha+1$.

Moreover, by Frobenius, $\alpha^{25} = (\alpha^5)^5 = (-\alpha^2+\alpha+1)^5 = (-\alpha^2)^5 + \alpha^5 +1^5 = -\alpha^{10} +\alpha^5 +1 =\ldots$, where the computation of $\alpha^{10}$ needs to be considered.

Comment: How can you argue that $ a, a^{5}$ and $a^{25}$ are distinct elements?

Comment: I guess because the constructed field is of order 125. Right?

Comment: thanks! @Wuestenfux for the answer.!