# Find the splitting field $E$ for $x^4+x+1$ over $\mathbb Z_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Find the splitting field $E$ for $x^4+x+1$ over $\mathbb Z_2$.

I proved $x^4+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2$.
So I tried to find the splitting field $E$ using Kronecker's theorem
$x+\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$ is a zero of $f(x)$
let $a=x+\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$ and let $F= \mathbb Z_2[X]/\langle x^4+x+1\rangle$
then there is $g(x)$ in $F[x]$ such that $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$, $\deg g(x)=3$
and I do not know what to do next.

Comment: I suggest you prove that if $a$ is a root, so is $a^2$ and so on ..

Comment: [A similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537229/prove-that-x3x1-splits-in-z-2x-x3x1/1537625#1537625)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to try a factorization as two polynomial of degree $2$, i.e $$(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f) = x^4+x+1$$

Since $cd = 1$ and we're in $\mathbb{F}_2$ necessarly we have $c=d=1=-1$.
Similarly $a=d=1$. Looking at the coefficient of $x^3$ we have $e+b=0$ but looking to the linear term we have $e+b =1$, contradiction.

Hence having the polynomial no roots and no factorization we have that the splitting field is the $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes of course

Comment: And I don't see that you've proved all the roots are in this simple extension (of course they are).

Comment: @ancientmathematician I assumed it is a known theorem the classification of finite fields